# Sign of the Euler characteristic of a variety of general type

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective complex variety of general type, minimal ($=K_X$ nef), of dimension $n$, and let $e(X)$ be its (topological) Euler characteristic. If $n=1$ or $2$, we have $(-1)^ne(X)>0$. I wonder if this holds for larger $n$: is this a known conjecture, or are there counter-examples?

Comment: This is true by a result of Will Sawin if $X$ admits a finite morphism to an abelian variety; see the Appendix to https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.01043

Comment: One can always blow up points to make the Euler characteristic positive (if $n > 1$). Maybe you want to assume that the canonical bundles is ample?

Comment: You can also blow up curves of large genus to make the Euler characteristic negative (if $n > 2$).

Comment: Oops! Right, I forgot to write "minimal". Corrected.